# Construction of maximal abelian extensions of totally real fields complex-analytically

Tags: nt.number-theory

So Hilbert's 12th problem has finally been solved for totally real fields (https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.02516), although $p$-adic analytically. There is an explicit construction of maximal abelian extensions of totally real fields through adjunction of Brumer-Stark units along with certain other elements.

The question is: what insights does this $p$-adic construction provide into how this might be accomplished complex analytically as was the original vision of Hilbert, already realized for the rational field, its imaginary quadratic extensions and a few other fields using division points on abelian varieties?

Dasgupta and Kakde mention that just as in their work integration might be required rather than just special values of complex analytic functions.